# MSDN firefox examples?

Tags: firefox, msdn

When I go to these examples using Firefox 3.6.3 and click the code examples it doesn't work:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7.aspx

I want confirmation that this is a Firefox compatibility problem, suspect my firewall.f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't switch languages in FF 3.6.3

Answer (score 2):

I can't switch languages in Chrome 5. Haven't been able to for some time. It used to work, or I'd be stuck on the default language instead of F#.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in Chrome.